# Université de X, Université X, X Université (où X le nom d'une ville)

Tags: usage, prépositions, noms-propres, toponymes

Selon mon expérience, la structure standard pour l'appellation d'une université nommée d'après le nom d'une ville est :

> Université de Nulle Part

*où « Nulle Part » est le nom de la ville.*

Ex. : Université de Lyon, Université de Toulon, Université de Lorraine, etc.

Je me demande dans quel cas l'absence de la préposition *de* est acceptable.

De plus, en anglais, la structure inverse, *(c'est-à-dire "Ville +  université*), est commune.

Ex. : *Stanford University, Harvard University, University College London, Lancaster University*, etc.

Une structure pareille serait-elle acceptable en français ? Par exemple :

> Nulle Part Université

Comment: Pour le dernier cas, as-tu par hasard d'autres exemples en tête que le récent « Sorbonne Universités » ?

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez : Aix-Marseille Université (https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_des_universités_en_France)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Je me demande dans quel cas l'absence de la préposition de est acceptable.

Le génitif est toujours matérialisé par la préposition *de* en français.

Il n'est pas naturel dans un texte standard de le rendre par une juxtaposition comme en anglais et encore moins avec une inversion. C'est :

> *Notre-Dame de Paris*, *Gare de Perpignan*, *Zoo de Vincennes*, *Préfecture des Bouches-du-Rhône*

et pas

> *Notre-Dame Paris*, *Gare Perpignan*, *Zoo Vincennes* ou *Bouches-du-Rhône Préfecture*.

Des entorses à cette règle accompagnent le [style télégraphique](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/style_t%C3%A9l%C3%A9graphique) utilisé du temps des télégrammes (ex. : *Arrive université Bordeaux lundi* pour *J'arrive à l'université de Bordeaux Lundi*), et que l'on peut retrouver dans le langage SMS

En revanche, quand la dénomination complète ne représente plus une relation de possession mais un nom composé d'un type (Université) et d'un nom propre (le nom de l'université, pas le nom d'une entité géographique indépendante de l'université), le *de* n'a plus lieu d'être et sera le plus souvent omis.

En conséquence, il n'existe pas de lieu nommé *Panthéon - Sorbonne Paris 1*, donc:

> Université Panthéon - Sorbonne Paris 1.

Il existe un lieu nommé Cergy-Pontoise donc:

> Université de Cergy Pontoise

Pareil pour:

> Université Toulouse I Capitole
>
> Université de Lille
>
> etc.

Le *de* est rarement maintenu:

> Université de la Sorbonne Nouvelle Paris 3

Il n'est jamais utilisé si le nom de l'université est celui d'une personne :

> Université Claude Bernard
>
> Université Lumière

comme on dit

> Gare Saint Lazare

et pas

> Gare de Saint Lazare

---

> De plus, en anglais, la structure inverse, c-à-d ville+université, est commune.
>
> Ex. : Stanford University, Harvard University, University College London, Lancaster University, etc.
>
> Une structure pareille serait-elle acceptable en français ?

Cet ordre est typique des langues germaniques mais va à l'encontre des standards des langues romanes. On observe cependant quelques rares entorses comme *Bretagne-Nord* pour *Nord de la Bretagne*.

Il est vrai aussi que l'on trouve une gare RER/SNCF nommée *Nanterre-Université* mais ici, on ne nomme pas l'université mais on précise de laquelle des gares de Nanterre il s'agit en opposition avec *Nanterre-Ville* et *Nanterre-Préfecture*. Il n'y a d'ailleurs pas de *Préfecture de Nanterre* puisqu'il s'agit de la préfecture des Hauts-de-Seine.

Voici cependant une exception : les trois grandes Universités de l'académie d'Aix-Marseille ont été regroupées en une seule entité en 2012 qui a pris pour nom:

[Aix-Marseille Université](https://www.univ-amu.fr/fr/universite).

C'est un anglicisme manifeste et certainement voulu pour faciliter la promotion de l'université à l'international.

D'autre part, en 2015, les deux universités de Montpellier ont fusionné et la nouvelle entité a pris pour nom :

[Université Montpellier](https://www.umontpellier.fr/universite/histoire-de-luniversite)

Une explication de l'absence de préposition est qu'il ne s'agit pas (ou plus) de l'université de Montpellier, mais de la fusion des universités *Montpellier 1* et *Montpellier 2*. On a simplement retiré les chiffres pour baptiser la nouvelle université.

Answer (score 1):

L'Université de Lorraine ? C'est Très bien ça [l'Université de Lorraine!](http://www.atilf.fr/) Très très bien! (eh oui! La référence fréquente ici, c'est de là qu'elle vient.)

Ha! Avant c'était celle de... Nancy!

L'absence de la préposition est parfaitement acceptable et ce depuis au moins que beaucoup d'universités **de xyzt** ne se trouvent plus à xyzt...

Je pense par exemple à l'Université **de** Vincennes (aujourd'hui à Saint-Denis) que l'on appelle aujourd'hui Université Paris VIII Vincennes Saint-Denis.

Le cas est aussi particulier pour Paris. Dire L'Université de Paris c'est ne se référer qu'à... la Sorbonne et... à un autre temps... ;)

Pas d'inversion en tous les cas. *Horresco referens!* Ha! allez! Pour appeler une station de métro, un arrêt de bus... je dis pas.

Answer (score 1):

1. L'acceptabilité ou la légitimité de l'existence des termes d'une langue, comme souvent, ce n'est pas une question de majorité choisissant d'utiliser une construction particulière, ni vraiment une question de minorité influente faisant la même chose, mais une question de groupe d'intérêt avec un objectif plus ou moins bien défini et qui n'est pas nécessairement celui d'améliorer le langage. Il n'y a pratiquement aucun critère d'acceptabilité; que les Belges décident demain, selon l'idée qu'ils en ont d'être une perspective raisonnable, de supprimer les règles d'accord du participe passé, et les participes passés sans s sont acceptables, tout au moins dans une langue qui n'est déjà pas tout à fait le français, c'est à dire le français belge.
   Omettre la préposition « de » dans les noms composés qui nomment les universités est une possibilité matérielle, sans aucun doute; il y a peu qui ne soit pas une possibilité matérielle en matière de langage; on le voit tous les jours dans la langue française; par exemple la place traditionnelle de certains compléments dans les phrases a été récemment changée sans que cela cause le moindre débat ni découle d'aucun digne de publicité; des expressions toutes faites sont ré-introduites avec des modifications (forme ou sens ou les deux) qu'aucune autorité ne justifie, sauf l'autorité de celui/celle qui écrit ou parle; des pronoms relatifs qui étaient jusqu'à présent obligatoires sont omis sans que quiconque y trouve quoi que ce soit d'inacceptable. Cette omission de « de » dont il est question n'est qu'un autre cas de modification du langage, bien que très différent par nature puisqu'il n'est considéré pour l'instant qu'en tant que possibilité et non imposé. Il est évident, vu les innombrables cas de  composés formés sur ce modèle (même préposition, même relation), que l'on introduit une nouvelle exception à une règle. Si l'on pense selon des critères donnés d'évaluation de l'apport au langage qu'il y a un intérêt à utiliser cette nouvelle tournure comment, tâche plus difficile, évaluer que cela  vaille la peine de la complexité qui est ajouté? Il est clair à tout étudiant d'un ou plusieurs langage que ce n'est souvent pas tant la règle qui constitue la difficulté que les innombrables exceptions immanquablement associées à son utilisation. En ce qui concerne cette idée d'omission il n'y a de bien évident qu'une économie de deux lettres, en gardant toutefois à l'esprit que les petits ruisseaux font les grandes rivières. En conclusion, je dois dire que je ne pense pas qu'il y ait une autorité reconnue qui oserait se hasarder à émettre la moindre opinion professionnelle sur ce sujet; si des normes existent elles ne peuvent être que le produit informel d'une expérience personnelle d'individus dans les professions concernées directement par le langage.
2. Bien sûr, dire « Paris II Université » est une possibilité de plus; d'ailleurs on trouve déjà « université de Aix en Provence » et « Aix en Provence université lettres » et « L'université d'Aix-Marseille, ou Aix-Marseille Université ». La [tendance](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universit%C3%A9_de_Provence_Aix-Marseille_I) existe, elle est lancée. Croyez-vous qu'elle résulte d'une décision étudiée reposant sur des principes reconnus? Ce n'est qu'un exemple de plus parmi des quantités d'autres dans la tourmente des changements largement incontrôlés qui ont toujours fait évoluer les langues.